# EasyPHP with PEAR installation

Tags: pear

I am trying to install PEAR with EASYPHP. I get to the batch file where it asks about the file layout. I am not sure what to set. I get where to put my public web files directory but am lost on the other ones. Please help?

1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : C:\EasyPHP\php
2. Temporary directory for processing            : C:\EasyPHP\php\tmp
3. Temporary directory for downloads             : C:\EasyPHP\php\tmp
4. Binaries directory                            : C:\EasyPHP\php
5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : C:\EasyPHP\php\pear
6. Documentation directory                       : C:\EasyPHP\php\docs
7. Data directory                                : C:\EasyPHP\php\data
8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : C:\EasyPHP\php\cfg
9. Public Web Files directory                    : C:\EasyPHP\php\www

   1. Tests directory                               : C:\EasyPHP\php\tests
   2. Name of configuration file                    : C:\Windows\pear.ini
   3. Path to CLI php.exe                           : .

PHP is under EasyPHP\php

Comment: I've been trying to get Propel to work with my pear installation and I think it has to do with choosing the wrong paths

Answer (score 0):

The settings are fully ok. Just make sure to add the `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Also, it seems you don't have any problems as your question doesn't ask about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a BAT file that does the PEAR installation steps for you...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\php\go-pear.bat`

It also has most of the file-paths preconfigured, so you don't really need to change anything.